# How to avoid affecting other code when panic error or something else in golang

Tags: exception, go, runtime-error, panic

I am writing a monitor program that will merge into company's system. When the program running, seldom panicked some error since a variety of problem such as a few other's server doesn't obtain the rule of http, network error or anything else.I fix most of them but **I am still afraid of influence on the master program by possibly potential errors.**

From company's aspect, the stability of master program is most important, secondly, monitoring's result, the stability of monitoring is low-priority.

Is there have a method can isolate error? For example,"try...except Exception..." in python to ignore error(Admittedly, Not recommended)How to avoid effect  other code when panic error or something else in golang

Answer (score 3):

With panics, you can use [recover](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics) like this

```
func recoverExample() {
    defer func() {
        if panicMessage := recover(); panicMessage != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Panic '%v' captured", panicMessage)
        }
    }()
    panic("Oh no!")
}
```

With output:

```
Panic 'Oh no!' captured
```

Answer (score 1):

User recover function at the top of your function in which you have the chances of getting error. Don't use `panic` as it will stop the execution of your code. Use below code snippet. Also It will print the log which will let you know in which function the exception occurred.

```
defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        log.Println("Recovered in custom function", r)
    }
}()
```